# Disable Tab key press inside TinyMCE editor using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, tabs, tinymce

I want to disable TAB keypress once I am inside the TinyMCE editor in my Rails application interface.

I have used the below given code to block the Tab keypress in the interface, but it is working outside the editor only.

```
$(document).keydown(function(objEvent) {
    if (objEvent.keyCode == 9) {  //tab pressed
        objEvent.preventDefault(); // stops its action
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to affect tab key behavior mentioned in this thread: http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=813